# How to load this javascript code automatically as soon as window load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I searched in this community, answers are available but does not work for my code.
Although my code works when I use button OnClick but I don't want to load it from within the body.Please help to load this JavaScript code automatically as soon as window load.

```
<html lang="en">
<head><title>demo</title>

<script>
function removeElement(parentDiv, childDiv){
     //if (childDiv == parentDiv) { alert("The parent div cannot be removed.");}

     if (document.getElementById(childDiv)) {     
          var child = document.getElementById(childDiv);
          var parent = document.getElementById(parentDiv);
          parent.removeChild(child); //parent.remove(parentDiv);
     }
     else {
          alert("Child div has already been removed or does not exist.");
          return false;
     }
};
</script>
</head>
<body> <!-- I don't want to load it in body onLoad="removeElement('parent','child');" -->

    <div id="parent" style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px;">
     I am the parent div.
        <div id="child" style="border: 1px solid green; padding: 10px;">
        I am a child div within the parent div.
        </div>
    </div>

<input type="button" value="Remove Element" onClick="removeElement('parent','child');">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As soon as window load, but not before?

Comment: If it is possible, also before.

Comment: Then put a script tag after the element to be removed (for example before `</body>`) saying `removeElement('parent','child');`, you don't have to wait for `onload` to fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `window.onload = function() { removeElement('parent','child'); }` before `</script>`

Comment: With pleasure :)

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap you code in a 'DOM ready event'

```
$(function() {
    // your code here
}
```

That is the short handed version, alternatively you can use:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // your code here
}
```

Note: your question has the 'jquery' tag so, you should reference this on your file also if you wish to utilise this library, for example:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```